# Selecting distinct values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble finding the solution to the following question:

> Which suppliers (lev) can only supply articles that are being sold by the hobby department?

- The suppliers are in the table *leverancier*
- The articles are in the table *artikel*
- The table *inkart* connects *leverancier* and *artikel*
- The departments are in the table *afdeling*
- The table *verkart* connects *artikel* and *afdeling*

[image]

The query I got so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT leverancier.lev 
FROM leverancier

JOIN inkart ON leverancier.lev = inkart.lev
JOIN artikel ON inkart.art = artikel.art
JOIN verkart ON artikel.art = verkart.art
JOIN afdeling ON verkart.afd = afdeling.afd

WHERE afdnaam = 'Hobby'
```

But this still includes suppliers who, besides hobby articles, also supply other articles. What would be the best way to filter them out?

Comment: Are you going to solve all your homework assessments here?

Comment: 2 `JOIN`'s to `afdeling`: the current on you already have (move the `WHERE afdnaam = 'Hobby'` to the `ON` clause, but that's a bit of a personal preference), making sure they can sell `Hobby` dept articles, the second one: `LEFT JOIN afdeling a2 ON verkart.afd = a2.afd AND a2.afdnaam != 'Hobby'`, drop your `DISTINCT`, use a proper `GROUP BY`, and add a `WHERE a2.afd IS NULL`.

Comment: @Wrikken `afdeling.afdnaam != 'Hobby'` is not a `JOIN` condition. I don't agree with this part, in a semantical sense.

Comment: @Lucia Pasarin: it was a typo, should be `a2.afdnaam !='Hobby'`, and then it is a clause for the join on `a2`. I saw & fixed it, but thanks for the heads up anyway ;)

Comment: No, what I meant is that it is not a condition applied to the `JOIN`, but only to a2 or afdeling table, whatever you call it.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin: yes, a join _on that condition_ (as a assume `afdnaam` is a column of `afdeling`). Which means it does not belong in the `WHERE` clause but in the `LEFT JOIN`, with good reason, because we'd like the `LEFT JOIN` to _fail_ and deliver our wanted `NULL` (no `afdeling` with another `afdnaam` then `'Hobby'`).

Comment: @Joren: it does matter - it's a sign for you that you need to read material once again, not come to get the ready to use solution (we assume you want to learn not cheat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT leverancier.lev , AFDNAAM
FROM leverancier
JOIN inkart ON leverancier.lev = inkart.lev
JOIN artikel ON inkart.art = artikel.art
JOIN verkart ON artikel.art = verkart.art
JOIN afdeling ON verkart.afd = afdeling.afd
WHERE AFDNAAM = 'HOBBY'
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT leverancier.lev , AFDNAAM
FROM leverancier
JOIN inkart ON leverancier.lev = inkart.lev
JOIN artikel ON inkart.art = artikel.art
JOIN verkart ON artikel.art = verkart.art
JOIN afdeling ON verkart.afd = afdeling.afd
WHERE AFDNAAM <> 'HOBBY'
```

Comment: The `EXCEPT` didn't work for me, but with a `NOT IN`, it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is using aggregation:

```
SELECT leverancier.lev , AFDNAAM
FROM leverancier JOIN
     inkart
     ON leverancier.lev = inkart.lev JOIN
     artikel
     ON inkart.art = artikel.art JOIN
     verkart ON artikel.art = verkart.art JOIN
     afdeling ON verkart.afd = afdeling.afd
GROUP BY leverancier.lev
HAVING MIN(AFDNAAM) = MAX(AFDNAAM) and
       MIN(AFDNAAM) = 'HOBBY';
```

That is, `'HOBBY'` is the only department in the supplier data.

Comment: If I `GROUP BY AFDNAAM`, isn't `MIN(AFDNAAM) = MAX(AFDNAAM)` always true? It would make a bit more sense to me it was just `GROUP BY leverancier.lev`, not `GROUP BY leverancier.lev, AFDNAAM`, or am I missing a trick here?

Comment: @Wrikken . . . Thank you for catching that.  That should not have been included in the `group by` clause.